# Identify the movies through equations

Tags: knowledge, visual, movies

*Each letter in these equations stands for a movie.*

> a = b + c
> d = e - c
> e = f × b

---

***Identify the movies 'a' to 'f' using these directors.***

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pictured directors are (in order of presentation):

> [Alfred Hitchcock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Hitchcock), [John Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Ford), [George Gallo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Gallo), [Ron Howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Howard), [Joel Schumacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Schumacher), and [Dan Trachtenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Trachtenberg).

However, they do not equate to the letters a-f in this order. To work this out, we need to look at...

> ...movies by these directors which have **numbers in their titles**. Specifically, we need the following:
>
>  a: *The Number 23* (Joel Schumacher)
>  b: *Apollo 13* (Ron Howard)
>  c: *10 Cloverfield Lane* (Dan Trachtenberg)
>  d: *29th Street* (George Gallo)
>  e: *The 39 Steps* (Alfred Hitchcock)
>  f: *Three Mounted Men*, or, alternatively, *Three Jumps Ahead* (John Ford)

This then satisfies all the equations...

> ...when the numbers from the titles are used in place of the variables:
>
>  a = b + c
>  d = e - c
>  e = f × b
>
>  23 = 13 + 10
>  29 = 39 - 10
>  39 = 3 x 13